# How can I create assignment rule on Account, Contact and opportunities objects?

Tags: trigger, process-builder, workflow, field-update, assignment-rules

I want to create assignment rule on standard objects (Account/contact/opportunity) I couldn't find, is it not possible to create assignment rule on Account/contact/opportunity objects ?

My Scenario - When the Account/contact/opportunity record Industry field value changed from "Agriculture" to "Electronics", the business wants the record owner to be automatically assigned from "AAA" to "BBB".

How can i achieve this scenario?

Comment: Depending on the underlying need for your question, Territory Management *may* work for your use case. If you're interested, consider setting up Territory Management in a Sandbox to see how it works, and check out the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[Assignment Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_leadrules.htm&type=5) are supported on the Lead and Case objects.

> Assignment rules automate your organization’s lead generation and support processes. Use lead assignment rules to specify how leads are assigned to users or queues. Use case assignment rules to determine how cases are assigned to users or put into queues.

You can use either declarative or programmatic automation for this purpose on other objects, but you cannot use Assignment Rules.

Comment: which programmatic automation process I can easily accomplish for these objects?

Comment: Programmatic automation means Apex triggers. If you don't want to write Apex, [pick a business process automation feature](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_whichtool).

Answer (score 0):

This kind of use-case can be achieved with AppExchange apps such as SuperRoundRobin:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FR4MkUAL